# Why does SSH hang at the end of these commands and how can I make it exit?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, openssh, remote-control

I run this:

```
ssh -t -vvv -i ~/.ssh/druid-keypair -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${INSTANCE_ADDRESS} <<EOI

# Setup Oracle Java
...

# Install dependencies - mysql must be built from source, as the 12.04 apt-get hangs
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password diurd'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password diurd'
sudo apt-get -q -y -V --force-yes --reinstall install mysql-server-5.5

echo "ALL DONE with druid environment setup!"
exit
EOI
```

Note: I have tried with and without -t in ssh.

The debug output from -vvv is this:

```
...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
ALL DONE with druid environment setup!
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
```

And then the process just sits there forever. Why won't the ssh command end? I have tried with -t and without, and I have tried with the exit and without. It doesn't make a difference :(

Update: When I type 'jobs' at the end of the script, I see:

```
JOBS:
[1]-  Running                 nohup bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties 2>&1 > /dev/null &
[2]+  Running                 nohup bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

How can I run these services and still have an ssh session that ends?

Update: I now manually disown these processes. The thing still doesn't exit. WTF mate?

Update: When executing line by line, two commands don't return to shell without hitting CR:

```
nohup bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
nohup bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
```

Comment: Try to use -q (quiet mode) instead of -vvv (verbose mode).

Comment: no effect. -vvv was just to debug.

Comment: SSH to server and execute all these commands one by one to figure out hang reason.

Comment: Thats the thing - none of them hang! This works fine in console.

Comment: Does it work if you replace the contents of the <<EOI block with something like "echo 1"?

Comment: Yes. Two commands hang until you hit CR: 

nohup bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
nohup bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &

Comment: I redirect output of these two commands to >/dev/null and they no longer hang until CR. But the ssh still hangs :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Typically, SSH terminal sessions hang if there are still background connections still open. By background connections, I mean things such as:

- X11 window forwarding
- STDOUT and STDERR

Have a look at the connections that are still active on your hung SSH session by typing `~#` in your hung SSH terminal.

It could be that your script is opening sessions that you didn't realize. Or your remote machine's terminal configs like `.profile` (or `.bashrc`, etc.) may have something in it that establishes a session. Good luck hunting!

By the way, some of the other escape sequences offered by OpenSSH clients may also be useful:

```
Supported escape sequences:
  ~.  - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
  ~B  - send a BREAK to the remote system
  ~C  - open a command line
  ~R  - Request rekey (SSH protocol 2 only)
  ~^Z - suspend ssh
  ~#  - list forwarded connections
  ~&  - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
  ~?  - this message
  ~~  - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

One other thing, if you want your SSH to just run your commands and immediately exit -- that is, you don't want a remote terminal session -- you can use the `-f` option to `ssh`. That will force the SSH connection to be a background job.

Comment: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)

This is what I get. Does this mean anything?

Comment: `-f` works for me.

Comment: I heard of -n for the same purpose but that didnt work for me!

Comment: Does a background process count as a `background connection` and can one `disown` the background process so the ssh connection doesn't hang?

Comment: if by chance anyone used this in connection with sshpass , it is necessary to pass the -f parameter to the  ssh command itself of course and not to the sshpass command